# What is legacy gateway submission in spark cluster mode of deployment?

Tags: apache-spark

I am executing the spark-submit command below.

```
  dse spark-submit --jars $JARS \
 --executor-memory $EXECUTOR_MEMORY \
 --total-executor-cores $TOTAL_EXECUTOR_CORES \
 --deploy-mode "cluster" \
 --supervise \
 --driver-class-path $JARS_COLON_SEP \
 --class $CLASS_NAME $APP_JAR
```

I am getting warning

```
WARN  2016-03-12 09:27:18,651 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:7077.

Warning: Master endpoint spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
```

When I gave the master URL with 6066 this warning is gone. I understand that master URL must be provided with port number 6066 to deploy in cluster mode.

My questions are

- What is the legacy submission gateway means ?
- Does that means it is submitted in client mode and supervise flag will not work?